# How to get data from more than one json api

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have more than one json api ex: api1 ,api2 and api3
Each one of them has different  structure from the others,
 I want to get data from these three api and combine them in one recycler view , i searched about these subject but couldn’t get any useful tutorial  i am already using retrofit for fetch data from only one api , should i using rxjava withe retrofit to do what i want And how .

Comment: how exactly do you want to recombine the json? you could pick individual data: new_json={name:api1.name, title:api2.title} or just combine them: new_json={json_api1, json_api2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for the `zip` method. It basically takes many observables, waits for their items - all of them- to arrive and then merges them.

So you can basically do each API call in an observable, whatever they return you'll get it all and do whatever you want with them in order to prepare them to be included in your recyclerview, and finally when the whole operation succeeds you'll populate your recyclerview.

```
Observable obs1 = Observable.fromCallable(// Callable 1);
Observable obs2 = Observable.fromCallable(// Callable 2);
Observable obs3 = Observable.fromCallable(// Callable 3);

Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, obs3, (o1, o2, o3) -> // something)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(o -> {
               // on success
        });
```